# Interactive HTML5 charts in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Jaspersoft Studio (Proffesional Edition) uses a JavaScript library Highcharts and generates HTML5 interactive charts. 
Is it possible to create in Jaspersoft Studio pie chart like here - http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown - 
that is to click on a particular part of the pie chart appeared and flashed a smooth transition to drill-down report?
Is it possible to create and display such a report in preview mode?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two things, first of all you need to configure your library in jaspersoft studio:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/advanced-formatting-new-html5-charts

and after that you need visualize.js, a component of jaspersoft to conect reports and javascript libraries as you want.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/visualizejs

Cheers!
Alba.